# Connect to a virtual machine from host as if it was another network machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine on Oracle VirtualBox, hosting Windows 8.1.

My desktop is running Windows 10.

I would like to access the virtual machine from the host, as if it was another machine on the network. I need do to this to connect to a SQL Server instance running on the virtual machine.

Is there any configuration I need to do on the VirtualBox to allow this? The virtual machine doesn't show under Network like the other machines connected to my network.

I can ping my host machine from the virtual machine, but not the other way around.

--- UPDATE ---

Here's the ipconfig of the host:

```
Configuração de IP do Windows

   Nome do host. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : RB-DESKTOP
   Sufixo DNS primário . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   Tipo de nó. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Roteamento de IP ativado. . . . . . . . . . : não
   Proxy WINS ativado. . . . . . . . . . . . . : não

Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet 2:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-00
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::b578:8124:53a:6a79%8(Preferencial)
   Endereço IPv4 de Configuração Automática. . : 169.254.106.121(Preferencial)
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 269090855
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-2F-83-77-F4-6D-04-44-1B-D4
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                                 fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                                 fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Habilitado

Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : F4-6D-04-44-1B-D4
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::79c5:9174:9a50:c226%14(Preferencial)
   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.103(Preferencial)
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Concessão Obtida. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sábado, 11 de julho de 2015 07:23:11
   Concessão Expira. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sábado, 11 de julho de 2015 13:23:11
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 250899716
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-2F-83-77-F4-6D-04-44-1B-D4
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Habilitado
```

The Virtual Box host-only adapter has the 169.254.106.121 IP. But if I go to the guest machine, this is the ipconfig result:

```
ConfiguraçĂo de IP do Windows

   Nome do host. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : RB-VIRTUAL
   Sufixo DNS primário . . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Tipo de nó. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Roteamento de IP ativado. . . . . . . . . . : nĂo
   Proxy WINS ativado. . . . . . . . . . . . . : nĂo

Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexĂo. . . . . . : 
   DescriçĂo . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-02-A3-D6
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   ConfiguraçĂo Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::5d28:2ae0:f5f9:f950%3(Preferencial) 
   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15(Preferencial) 
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   ConcessĂo Obtida. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sábado, 11 de julho de 2015 11:36:03
   ConcessĂo Expira. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : domingo, 12 de julho de 2015 11:36:04
   Gateway PadrĂo. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 50855975
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-31-FE-88-08-00-27-02-A3-D6
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Habilitado

Adaptador de túnel isatap.{EF2C4D17-105C-44C3-B6CA-2A5AA8552352}:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexĂo. . . . . . : 
   DescriçĂo . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : NĂo
   ConfiguraçĂo Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim

Adaptador de túnel Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexĂo. . . . . . : 
   DescriçĂo . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : NĂo
   ConfiguraçĂo Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:1418:21e4:44c8:8e88(Preferencial) 
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::1418:21e4:44c8:8e88%5(Preferencial) 
   Gateway PadrĂo. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : ::
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 134217728
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-31-FE-88-08-00-27-02-A3-D6
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Desabilitado
```

There, the ip is 10.0.2.15 this is the IP I'm trying to ping from the host machine. Is that correct that the IP on guest machine is not the same that is showing on the host adapter?

Comment: Do you have the host-only network configured?

Comment: You need to install a host only adapter on your host through virtualbox

Comment: Yes, I have a host-only adapter on my network connections, together with my ethernet connection. Also on my virtual machine, on the network section it is connected to 'NAT'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple!

- Change the network adapter to `Bridged Adapter`
- Click OK.
- Test

[image: Network adapter settings]